# extracting part of a string in a column and retain other columns

Tags: awk, grep

I have a tab- separated file with many rows like this :

```
1    ILM-rs199    info1    info2    info3
2    aws-rs2778   info4    info5    info6
3    345-678945   info7    info8    info9
4    aws-rs789    info10   info11   info-rs789
```

I want to extract 2nd and 4th column and in the second column I want only the string starting with rs and the numbers following it like this :

```
rs199    info2
rs2778   info5
rs789    info11
```

I was able to extract the second column alone with the following command:

```
egrep -o 'rs[0-9]*' filename
```

gives

```
rs199 
rs2778
rs789
```

but I got stuck when I had to also keep the other columns

I was thinking of using  egrep (for extracting rs nos in 2nd column) inside awk but could'nt finish it.

Comment: Does the second column *always* have a `-` before the rsID? And is your file space-delimited or do you have tabs?

Comment: @terdon : tab separated . No, it is not necessary that there is a - always before rsID

Comment: Ah, crap. Please include an example with no `-` then, my original answer depended on that. By the way, you might be interested in our new sister site, [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Wait, so you can also have cases with no `rs` in the second column? What should happen there? Please take a few minutes and think about all the possible cases. Making constant changes that invalidate our answers means we will be wasting your time (and ours) giving you solutions that don't work for your data.

Comment: OK, apologies. finishing it

Comment: Please also make sure to make your requirements clear. Why is the 3d line skipped? Should we *only* return data for cases where the 2nd field contains the string `rs` followed by numbers? Should other lines be skipped? Should we try and find a valid rsID from another field?

Comment: Please stick with the second column alone . edited the qn . We need to return data where the second field contains the string rs[numbers] but the same rs[numbers] might also be in one other column as well. Yes, other lines with no rsID's should be skipped . Please dont go for rsID in other fields .

Comment: Then why do you only show two lines of output if three of your input lines have rsIDs in the second column? Why is the 4th line skipped? Once again, I will ask you to take the time to think about your needs and express them clearly. We can't guess them.

Comment: Edited again. Yes, it takes time to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ # assuming `rs[digits]` string will match only in 2nd column
$ # string matched within () will get printed
$ perl -lne 'print /(rs\d+\t)[^\t]+\t([^\t]+)/' ip.txt
rs199   info2
rs2778  info5

$ # to match from 2nd column only
$ perl -lne 'print /^[^\t]+\t[^\t]*(rs\d+\t)[^\t]+\t([^\t]+)/' ip.txt
rs199   info2
rs2778  info5

$ # to get some other column, say 2nd and 5th
$ perl -lne 'print /^[^\t]+\t[^\t]*(rs\d+\t)(?:[^\t]+\t){2}([^\t]+)/' ip.txt
rs199   info3
rs2778  info6
```

to print only if match is found:

```
$ perl -lne '/^[^\t]+\t[^\t]*(rs\d+\t)(?:[^\t]+\t){1}([^\t]+)/ && print $1,$2' ip.txt
rs199   info2
rs2778  info5
$ perl -lne '/^[^\t]+\t[^\t]*(rs\d+\t)(?:[^\t]+\t){2}([^\t]+)/ && print $1,$2' ip.txt
rs199   info3
rs2778  info6
```

Previous solution, where string to be extracted where next to each other

```
$ # assuming the shell being used supports $'' strings
$ grep -o $'rs[0-9]*\t[^\t]*' ip.txt
rs199   info1
rs2778  info4
```

Comment: Hi Sandeep , Unfortunately the columns that I wanted to extract are not located next to each other .

Comment: @user3683555 what do you mean? And how were we supposed to guess that? Please [edit] your question and make sure your example file accurately represents your data.

Comment: @terdon : edited the question.

Comment: the same rs number is present in one more column sometimes , which makes it tricky

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few options:

1. awk

   ```
   $ awk -vOFS="\t" '{sub(/.*-/,"",$2);print $2,$4}' file 
   rs199   info1
   rs2778  info3
   ```

   This will remove everything until the first `-` from the second field and then print the resulting 2nd field along with the 4th.
2. Perl

   ```
   $ perl -pe 's/.*?-*(rs\d+\t)\S+\t(\S+).*/$1\t$2/' file 
   rs199   info2
   rs2778  info5
   ```

   As above, this will fail if you can have `rs` in the 1st field. A more robust approach would be:

   ```
   $ perl -F'\t' -lane '$F[1]=~s/.+-//; print join "\t",@F[1,3]' file
   rs199   info2
   rs2778  info5
   ```

   This removes any characters before the `-` in the 2nd field (it will do nothing if the 2nd field doesn't have an `-`) and then prints the 2nd and 4th fields.

Comment: I was trying with awk as well . The approach with - fails if you have another row with  345-678945 because there is no rsID in that string.

Comment: I will try to use the perl solution  and validate it

Comment: @user3683555 no, don't "validate" it. Instead, take the time to look at your data carefully and make sure your example is correct. You seem to want to skip lines where the second field doesn't have an rsID (no `rs`), but *you don't mention that*. We can't give you correct answers if you don't give us correct examples to work with. So please edit your question and make sure you are giving valid example data.

Comment: Yes, I want to skip lines where there is no rsID. Also, please note that the same rsID is present in other columns sometimes, which makes it tricky

Comment: Instead of sub in the awk command , I was trying to see if I can use grep, but could'nt finish it

Answer (score 1):

I have done by below method

inputfile

```
ILM-rs199    info1    info2    info3
aws-rs2778   info4    info5    info6
345-678945   info7    info8    info9
aws-rs789    info10   info11   info-rs789
```

command

```
awk -F "-" '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' inputfile | awk '$2 ~ /^rs[0-9]/{print $2,$4}'
```

output

```
rs199 info2
rs2778 info5
rs789 info11
```

Comment: awesome dude.  I was looking for this syntax '$2 ~ /^rs[0-9]/